# Uploading multiple files when user clicks on [add more]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a wizard, in some steps I want the user to be able to upload multiple files (no limit) each with description. by default one `FileUpload` control should be visible, and by clicking (add more) new once are created.

I need something like [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/10/02/asp.net-multiple-file-uploading.aspx) . 
when I tried to run this code alone, it is working just fine, but when I added it to my website it doesn't work ( the default `FileUpload` control is not created ) and the error occurs when I click (Upload)

I'm appreciating any help to fix the code, or any new ideas.
if my question is not clear enough or I need to give more information please let me know

Answer (score 2):

- [Fancy Upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/#how-to) - *quite nice, but no feedback from server, uses mootools not jq*
- [MultiPowUpload](http://demo.element-it.com/Examples/multipow/index.htm) - *looks good, resumes, no flash cookie bug, $149*
- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) - *looks reasonable, real world though?*
- YUI - *mostly custom code, will work but tedious*
- [SWFUpload](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/) - *no progress bar, otherwise pretty basic & good*
- [JQuery Multifile (fyneworks.com)](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) - *inconsistent browser support*
- devex / [telerek](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)
- [PL UPload](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php) - *nice, but missing 'retry' and error reporting.  may be able to add*
- [Plupload](http://element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx)

---

U can look to these controls and select the appropriate one.