# asp.net file uploader not working with grid view

Tags: asp.net

What wrong with this code ,why doesn't it working ,please suggest me.I'm uploading csv file to display in gridview,but control doesn't going inside if loop.

```
if (csv_upload.HasFile)
            {
                string target = Server.MapPath("~/Upload");
                lbl_status.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
                csv_upload.SaveAs(target);

                string constring = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Text;",
                    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(target + "\\" + csv_upload.FileName));

                string cmdstring = string.Format("SELECT * FROM 0}",System.IO.Path.GetFileName(target + "\\" + csv_upload.FileName));

                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(constring,cmdstring);

                System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

            oda.Fill(ds);

            GridView1.DataSource=ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: Can you please also post some more code. You say that there is a problem with going into the if-loop, but you only supply the if-loop. Please post also how you create the variable csv_upload. (Is it a custom class, then please also post that class). Otherwise, it is very difficult for us to see what is going on.
Thank you.

Comment: Actually based on the methods you use with the variable, I could find something. Is csv_upload a file or a directory. In case of a File, you need to use the method csv_upload.isFile

Comment: csv_upload is  fileuploader control,now i got result.actually i was placed all the controls in ajax updatepanel ;so that debugger is not go through if_loop.   Now I am having another problem 'It could not displaying the csv data into gridview.....is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments you use the `fileuploader` in an update panel.

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) the FileUpload control is not compatible with an AJAX UpdatePanel.

You can use a third party component that can do that. It's called [swfuploa](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) . It is free to use and open source.
also look to my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9278317/418343).